# Linear interpolation in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, goalseek

I want to know how I can programmatic use my linear interpolate equation without having the user or myself to use the Goal Seek function in the data menu, well I could use the function but I want it to be "hidden" and just update the cell when the user is finished writing the required number in the other fields.

Answer (score 1):

The functions you're looking for are SLOPE and INTERCEPT, to determine the coefficient of, well, slope and intercept of the fitting line.